# How to add another each function in PUG

Tags: html, iteration, pug, each

```
.product--production-wrapper.flex-row.col-x4
    - for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    - var imagePath = ('assets/img/product-image/')
    each picture, bedFurniture in ['bed-1.jpg', 'bed-2.jpg', 'bed-3.jpg', 'bed-4.jpg', 'bed-5.jpg', 'bed-6.jpg']
        article.bed.card
            .product--image
                a(href="#"): img(src= imagePath + picture)
            .product--desc-wrapper.flex-row
                .product--name-href
                    h5 Product Name
                    a(href="#") Bed
                a(href="#").price $3999
```

I create for **article** tag a loop and *each function* for **image** tag inside of it, but i can't figure it out how to add *each function* for **Product Name** and **Price** in this code. I will be grateful if someone helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.product--production-wrapper.flex-row.col-x4
    - for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    - var imagePath = ('assets/img/product-image/')
    each item in [ {image: 'bed-1.jpg', price: '1999', name: 'product name 1'}, {image: 'bed-2.jpg', price: '345', name: 'product name 2'}, {image: 'bed-3.jpg', price: '2329', name: 'product name 3'} ]
        article.bed.card
            .product--image
                a(href="#"): img(src=imagePath + item.image)
            .product--desc-wrapper.flex-row
                .product--name-href
                    h5= item.name
                    a(href="#") Bed
                a(href="#").price= item.price
```